# Question complexity, abstract algebra, a question of returning the material before the test

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, exponential-function, computational-complexity

Hello everyone this is my first time on the site, I am preparing for a test I will have in a few more days in the abstract algebra Course.

The lecturer gave us a database of questions without solutions, I solved them all, but I could not solve this question. I do not have to submit this question, it's just a question he gave in order to repeat the material.

the question:

[image]

I think the correct answer is a. If in case a, A and B have the same complexity, then in case b to B there will be a greater complexity, because it is now exponential.

b is incorrect, In my opinion in case a, it cannot be that B is a upper bound

c is incorrect, It cannot be that even in case a and in case b, B is a tight barrier.

d is incorrect, Exactly the same explanation as for C, that there are 2 to the constant power, it is still a number.

e is incorrect, because a current

So a is correct in my opinion, but I'm not sure

Comment: Please don't delete then repost your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4070507/242). This violates site rules.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands). Please give proper attribution to the source of all copied material.